# Shorter CASE ISNULL(qry, '')='' THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, isnull

Is there a shorter/better way to write this SQL statement?

**Edit:** the inner sql select statement is a placeholder, the actual statement is more complex.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN
        ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 x FROM y), '') = ''
    THEN 'No'
    ELSE 'Yes'
    END AS BooleanValue
```

It feels very kludgey because it compares the result of the select statement to null, then sets to an empty string if null; just to check if it is an empty string, and set it to what it actually needs to be: a 'yes' or 'no' string.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to get a yes/no or 1/0 answer for whether or not the inner SELECT statement is null. I probably could just skip the whole case statement, and when I use the value later, I could check if it equals `''`.

Comment: How about exists `(select top 1 x from y)`?

Comment: Are you trying to test if any rows are returned?  Or if a row is returned with `x` being `NULL` or empty string?

Comment: The inner select statement was a bad example, the actual select statement is more complex.

Comment: @JosephDykstra so can you please show your actual question?

Comment: The whole `CASE WHEN ISNULL(whatever, '') = '' THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END` seems silly because it compares to null, then sets to an empty string, just to check if it is an empty string, and set it to what it actually needs to be; a 'yes' or 'no' string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it a bit cleaner.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN
        (SELECT TOP 1 x FROM y) IS NULL
    THEN 'No'
    ELSE 'Yes'
    END AS BooleanValue
```

This removes one extra command and should have the same output.  I just tested it in sql server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 'Yes' FROM x), 'No') as Boolean
```